# Spring Security: How to customize remember-me request parameter name?

Tags: spring-security

I'm using `password-parameter` (as below) to customize the name of the request parameter which contains the password. How to do the same with remember-me (default `_spring_security_remember_me`) ?

```xml
<security:form-login password-parameter="j_password_input" ... />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options which I have explained in further detail below

- Use the Security Namespace with a BeanPostProcessor
- Use the services-ref and configure RememberMeServices Manually

### Use the Security Namespace with a BeanPostProcessor

The namespace does not have support for configuring the remember me parameter, but you can use a tip from the [FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-namespace-post-processor) on how to still use the namespace support, but customise the result. The trick is to use a `BeanPostProcessor` to set the parameter field on `AbstractRememberMeServices`. You can find an example of this below:

```java
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
    if (bean instanceof AbstractRememberMeServices) {
      AbstractRememberMeServices rememberMe = (AbstractRememberMeServices) bean;
      rememberMe.setParameter("myParamname");
    }
    return bean;
  }    
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) {
    return bean;
  }
}
```

Then you would need to use the namespace as you normally would and add MyBeanPostProcessor to your Spring configuration as shown below:

```xml
<security:http ..>
  ...
  <security:remember-me/>
</security:http>
<bean class="sample.MyBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

### Use the services-ref and configure RememberMeServices Manually

You can also use the [services-ref](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-remember-me-services-ref) attribute too, but this involves a little more configuration. For example, if you wanted you could use the following configuration:

```xml
<security:http ..>
  ...
  <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>
</security:http>
<bean id="rememberMeServices"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
  <property name="key" value="mustMatchRememberMeAuthenticationProvidersKey"/>
  <property name="parameter" value="myParamName"/>
  <!-- You must refer to a bean that implements UserDetailsService 
       in this example the bean id is userDetailsService -->
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Security 3.2.x, you can set this with the `remember-me-parameter` parameter on the `remember-me` element.