# PrimeFaces p:selectBooleanCheckbox for Spring Security "Remember me" changes name of checkbox input which causes "Remember me" to fail

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, primefaces

I have a JSF page which has this component:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me" label="Remember Me"/>
```

The exact input field ID/name `_spring_security_remember_me` is required by Spring Security. However, PrimeFaces generates it with the `_input` suffix as follows:

```
<div id="_spring_security_remember_me" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input id="_spring_security_remember_me_input" name="_spring_security_remember_me_input" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default"><span class="ui-chkbox-icon"></span></div>
</div>
```

Therefore the "Remember me" functionality fails to find the parameter. How can I solve it? Can I tell PrimeFaces to not suffix it with `_input`, or can I tell Spring Security to look for a different request parameter name for the "Remember me" checkbox?

Comment: A downvote for what? For me being inexperienced? At least tell me what should I do after you downvoted the question. I won't mind.

Comment: This seems like normal behavior to me. Someone probably downvoted this because this question isn't a legitimate question. If I understand correctly the code is working right?

Comment: I need a specific id string to be forwarded to the spring security login service. But primefaces forces the id and the name to have a suffix "_input". What do I do? Should I force the id to be changed using javascript? Why put the suffix in the first place, I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

```
<security:remember-me key="remember-me-security" services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="com.triune.services.CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService">
    <property name="key" value="remember-me-security" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="TRIUNE" />
    <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="1209600" />
    <property name="useSecureCookie" value="true" />
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    <property name="alwaysRemember" value="false" />
    <property name="parameter" value="_spring_security_remember_me_input"/>
</bean>
```

put a property named "parameter" with a value that equals to the id/name that primefaces generates.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can solve the issue you're having by passing a name in the element"</strike>

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me" name="_spring_security_remember_me" label="Remember Me"/>
```

**Edit:**

Since you cannot set a name for the input I guess your best move is to change the parameter for your remember-me-service. See [this question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653455/spring-security-how-to-customize-remember-me-request-parameter-name) for more info.

Comment: Nope, it's not defined in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is common practice in primefaces. All components are placed inside a div block specifying common css properties etc. This div block gets the id as it is the root element of the component. All other important child-elements which must be identiefieable (e.g like in this case the input element) get the original id + `_foo` assigned.

If you want to read the value of the component at clientside you can use the attribute `widgetVar` to specify a global js var referencing to the backing jquery object of the component. Turn on your debugger to find out what properties it has. Those js classes are mostly undocumented.

---

If you need the id at serverside though it gets a bit more complicated. First of all you must inject the component model into your backing bean using the `binding` attibute. Now having the `SelectBooleanCheckbox` model you can invoke `String clientId = checkbox.getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());` to retrieve the client id. Getting the input id is simple string string manipulation now: `String inputId = clientId + "_input";`

---

If your unsure about how a component behaves at client side, you can always take a look at its model and renderer. In this case both are located in the `org.primefaces.component.selectbooleancheckbox` package.

Comment: Is there any reason for them to force this behavior? Without giving any option to change the default setting :/

Comment: @William Its how they render their components and makes sense. The component do not just consist of the `<input>` tag itself. Assigning the id to the component container is pratically and "declares" the component as a independent isolated system.